# WordPress PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_action()

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

On my WordPress (3.9.1) website I'm using the below code in my functions.php to add the stylesheet to the header of the theme:

```
function myd_scripts_styles() { 
    wp_enqueue_style( 'richwp-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myd_scripts_styles' );
```

From time to time my error.log shows the following:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function add_action()

And it's referring to the above code. For me the code looks ok and it's also working as it should.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Where exactly are you using the code?

Comment: This is part of the functions.php

Comment: I just tested your code in my `functions.php` and **it's OK**, no Fatal errors... But the URI should be: `get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/your-style.css'`

Answer (score 0):

This Question is too old but i recently had the same problem in my theme. and i was able to solve the problem by turning off `allow_url_fopen` from php.ini file.

that is why it works on one server while generating error on another.

hope it will help for those who are still having this issue.